# "What's up with him?" vs. "What's with him?"

Tags: difference, phrase-usage, expressions

I'd like to know if there is any difference between these two phrases when they are used for expressing the feeling that you think something is wrong with somebody.

> He's acting very weird. What's up with him?

and

> He's acting very weird. What's with him?

Comment: Interesting question. I'd say there is no significant difference between those two queries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They both can be used to ask about the basis of an observation that something is wrong.  However, there is a subtle difference.

The question *What's with him?* almost always indicates that the speaker thinks that there is something wrong with him or his behavior.

The sentence *What's up with him?* can be used to mean the same thing, if there is a context indicating that there is a concern.  However, this sentence can be used in a neutral, non-critical way.

> I know Jim was trying to decide about his next job. What's up with him?

I can be a simple inquiry, where *What's with him?* is almost always negative.

Often the inflection is used as a clue.  For the phrase *What's with him?* the emphasis is often a very exaggerated stress on the *with* as in

> What's WITH him?

It also could be an exaggerated emphasis on *him*

> What's with HIM?

In the neutral use of the alternative, there might be a slight emphasis on two words

> What's *up* with *him*?

Comment: Nice answer - one minor nitpick:  I think the last example might be even more neutral with just "up" emphasized. To my ear, the more emphasis you add to "him", the more pejorative the implication seems to be.

Answer (score 3):

Both of these phrases mean the same thing: *What's the matter with him?* or *What's wrong with him?* or *What's his problem?* There are other phrases that mean the same as well.

Comment: They might be used on different occasions. You might ask, in a sympathetic tone of voice, _What's up with him?_ of someone who was ill, but I don't think you'd ask _What's with him?_

Comment: @Barrie: Maybe not in BrE, but _What's with him?_ is perfectly normal in AmE. Less accomplished speakers would certainly be prone to use fewer words: _Watt's wit him?_ instead of _Watt's amadda wit him?_ in New Joisey-ese.

Comment: @Barrie: I think you're onto something there. If someone was sick, though, I'd probably be more inclined to ask, "What's wrong with him?" than either of those. P.S. (to Bill) "What's with him?" may be normal AmE, but I don't think I'd use it for someone who is ill; it seems more apt when asking about someone in a bad mood than sick in bed.

Comment: I'm so used to _What's [something] with him_ that it sounds kinda weird to me.

Comment: Disagree--- in AmE *What's with him?* would not be commonly used for an ill person. It is definitely used more to refer to someone who is angry or upset.

Comment: @Aerovistae: You're certainly free to disagree. But I don't believe that you grew up in my New Jersey neighborhoods back in the 1940s and 1950s, so you can't tell me how we used the language. I did point out in my comment to Barrie that it was regional & even working-class and below. Maybe you missed those caveats. Besides, the OP asked about "phrases ... used for expressing the feeling that you think something is wrong with somebody": "**something is wrong**" doesn't necessarily mean _sick_. The OP said "**acting very weird**", not "_looks ill_".

Comment: @J.R.: I agree that people who speak **refined English** would be less inclined to say "What's with him?" when asking about a sick person (I know I mentioned that in my comment to Barrie), but the OP didn't ask about a "sick person": the OP asked about a person "acting very weird".

Comment: Bill, yes - just to clarify how we agree on this: _"What's with him?"_ is fine, even ordinary, for odd behavior (as the O.P. asked about), but it sounds off, or inappropriate, for a sick person (as Barrie mentioned as an aside).